# relabel hfs+ volumes

Tags: gparted, hfs+

I have read through all the man pages of my hfs-related packages (`hfsplus-tools`, `hfsutils`), and I cannot find a way to relabel a hfs+ volume. `gparted` also seems to be able on my system to do all the other operations on hfs+, but not change UUID and label (it can view them though, I suppose through `libblkid`). Is it really not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actions available on file systems are listed on the [GParted Features](http://gparted.org/features.php) page.  Currently (latest version 0.23.0) the **Label** and **UUID** features are not available for HFS and HFS+ file systems.  This is due to limitations in the underlying file system tools.